# An error occurred in convert MPEG4 to AMV via ffmpeg: AMV files only support 2 streams

Tags: ffmpeg

About March, at that time, I found about [convert MPEG4 to AMV via ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1649146/convert-mpeg4-to-amv-via-ffmpeg) in superuser. And successfully uses this command to convert MP4 to AMV:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.mp4 -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv
```

At that time, I was using ffmpeg of GIT version of windows. When I tried to run this line of code on Ubuntu, I was prompted that the AMV stream was not found. Then I got the answer on [Using ffmpeg to convert video: solution to rejected AMV container?](https://superuser.com/questions/1426454/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-video-solution-to-rejected-amv-container)

But when I tried this code on the GIT version of ffmpeg today, I got an error message:

```
C:\Users\26591\Documents>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.mp4 -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv
ffmpeg version 2022-08-29-git-f99d15cca0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
libavcodec     59. 42.103 / 59. 42.103
libavformat    59. 30.100 / 59. 30.100
libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
libavfilter     8. 46.103 /  8. 46.103
libswscale      6.  8.104 /  6.  8.104
libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.mp4':
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: mp41avc1
        creation_time   : 2017-09-29T13:11:57.000000Z
        encoder         : vlc 2.2.6 stream output
        encoder-eng     : vlc 2.2.6 stream output
Duration: 00:00:11.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 720 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 719 kb/s, 24.92 fps, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-29T13:11:57.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Codec AVOption block_size (set the block size) specified for output file #0 (C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
File 'C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> amv (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000028e3b9d6d00] [swscaler @ 0000028e3be000c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0000028e3b9d6d00] [swscaler @ 0000028e3be36e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0000028e3b9d6d00] [swscaler @ 0000028e3be7ae80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[amv @ 0000028e3abded40] AMV files only support 2 streams
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

Before this, this line of code is free of any warnings and errors. When ffmpeg prompts me that I have not selected any video stream, I modified the code to read:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.mp4 -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 -map 0:0 -c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv
```

However, the error has not changed, and I don't know why AMV only supports two streams. Why did this problem not appear in the previous git version ffmpeg? Can anyone help me solve this problem?(This is my conversion file:`https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-2O38Sq04QyJXREJ7rLAAcfTPx4Lp8H/view?usp=sharing`)

2022.09.01---According to pieru and ROTEM's comments, I changed another file. This video file is in WebM format, but this video has video stream and audio stream. I tried to use the modified command to convert it, but the error did not change at all:

```
C:\Users\26591\Documents>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\26591\Pictures\0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.webm -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 -map 0:0 -c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p C:\Users\26591\Videos\0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.amv
ffmpeg version 2022-08-29-git-f99d15cca0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
    libavutil      57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
    libavcodec     59. 42.103 / 59. 42.103
    libavformat    59. 30.100 / 59. 30.100
    libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
    libavfilter     8. 46.103 /  8. 46.103
    libswscale      6.  8.104 /  6.  8.104
    libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
    libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'C:\Users\26591\Pictures\0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.webm':
    Metadata:
        title           : アニメ_途中, ayaka
        URL             : http://ginziro.blog45.fc2.com/blog-entry-1102.html
        MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
        MINOR_VERSION   : 512
        COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomiso2avc1mp41
        ENCODER         : Lavf58.27.103
Duration: 00:00:24.26, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 1730 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.52.101 libvpx-vp9
      DURATION        : 00:00:24.207000000
Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandler
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.52.101 libopus
      DURATION        : 00:00:24.257000000
Codec AVOption block_size (set the block size) specified for output file #0 (C:\Users\26591\Videos\0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.amv) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> amv (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] [swscaler @ 000001c2d081cfc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] [swscaler @ 000001c2d083e840] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] [swscaler @ 000001c2d086c0c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d083ee40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d08600c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d083ee40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d08680c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d083ee40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d08600c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001c2d0831e40] [swscaler @ 000001c2d0810000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[amv @ 000001c2d06ac840] AMV files only support 2 streams
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

I have also tried to convert WebM files to MPEG4 files, but nothing has changed except that there are fewer warnings from swscaler(This is my conversion files:
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C59-mA8glObl4eyvf8vD2jj8lqAhEQla/view?usp=sharing`
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlM-eHv5RNZV8DtkI9lSG15IwbS3DQfr/view?usp=sharing`)

Comment: It looks like your input file `WebADB-Demo.mp4` has only a video stream and no audio stream... Please paste the entire output of the command.

Comment: In case the input file has no audio as commented by PierU, try adding silent audio stream: `ffmpeg -i C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=22050 -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 -shortest C:\Users\26591\Videos\WebADB-Demo.amv`

Comment: @PierU Perhaps, there is no audio output when the video is played (qwq). 
Due to the number of comment words, I can only provide Google cloud hard disk link for video `https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-2O38Sq04QyJXREJ7rLAAcfTPx4Lp8H/view?usp=sharing`

Comment: @Rotem I tried to use the command you sent under ffmpeg of GIT version of windows, but ffmpeg prompts that the options are not recognized: `Unrecognized option 'short'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: Please paste the full command and the entire output of the command.

Comment: @王王瀚 you can edit your own question to paste the entire output of the command (and the full command)

Comment: @PierU Thank you for reminding me (qwq). This is my first time to use superuser. The full log and commands have been modified

Comment: @Rotem The complete log output and commands have been modified in the issue details (qwq)

Comment: The full log confirms that your input file has no audio stream. Try generating a silent audio stream as suggested by @Rotem

Comment: @PierU I just changed a video file in WebM format through your suggestion. This video file has video stream and audio stream. However, the same error occurred in the conversion as in the original file. I tried to convert WebM to MPEG4, but the problem still hasn't been solved. I also revised the details of the problem. I hope you can help me again. (qwq)

Comment: @Rotem Sorry, I didn't notice you changed the command. I just tried this command again and the conversion was successful. However, I have a new problem now. Please look at the details of the problem again (XwX)

Comment: Remove `-map 0:0`. The following command works in my machine: `ffmpeg -i 0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.webm -s 160x120 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -vstrict -1 -r 25 -block_size 882 -map 0:0 -c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p 0801f452a88bdf167b0f308c4cd6e7d9.amv`. I suggest you to download `ffmpeg-release-full.7z`, version **5.1.1** from [www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds)

Comment: @Rotem Yes, thank you! The problem has been solved